# Android Map v2 marker bubble

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have a question regarding the bubble that pops up when you click on a map marker. I have searched the internet but no real satisfying answer. Basically my question is:  Is there any way for the bubble to appear on default without me clicking it?

In the code I've shown below this part:

```
MarkerOptions tousgårdsladen = new MarkerOptions()
    .position(TOUSGÅRDSLADEN).title("Activity Name")
    .snippet("Snippet");"
```

If you click the marker a bubble pops up with the text "Activity Name" so basically i want that bubble to appear as the markers are loaded without me clicking, and if you click it would give you more details about the activity where the marker is placed.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {


Activity activity;
double lat;
double lng;
LatLng currentPosition;
SeekBar seekBar;
TextView textView;
GoogleMap map;

static final LatLng TOUSGÅRDSLADEN = new LatLng(56.16266, 10.13851);
static final LatLng DORTESVE = new LatLng(56.15952, 10.13570);
static final LatLng GELLERUP = new LatLng(56.154633, 10.133679);

private HashMap<Marker, Event> eventMarkerMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e(tag, "inside create map_view");

    // Context
    activity = getActivity();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);

    SetMap();
    SetCameraLocation();

    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slide_bar_text);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slide_bar);
    SetSeekBar();

    return rootView;
}

private void SetCameraLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) activity
            .getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition,
                14));
    } else {
        // default is setted to Gellerup
        currentPosition = new LatLng(56.154633, 10.133679);
    }
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 14));

}

private void SetMap() {
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();

    if (map != null) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

        MarkerOptions tousgårdsladen = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(TOUSGÅRDSLADEN).title("Activity Name")
                .snippet("Snippet");
        ;
        MarkerOptions dortesve = new MarkerOptions().position(DORTESVE)
                .title("Activity Name").snippet("Snippet");
        map.addMarker(tousgårdsladen);
        map.addMarker(dortesve);
    }
}

private void SetSeekBar() {
    seekBar.setMax(2); // Three options
    seekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            int kilometers = 0;
            switch (progress) {
            case 0:
                kilometers = 2;
                break;
            case 1:
                kilometers = 4;
                break;
            case 2:
                kilometers = 6;
                break;
            }

            textView.setText(kilometers + " km");

            LoadTrack loadTrack = new LoadTrack();
            List<Location> list = loadTrack.decodeGPX(activity);

            PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions();
            line.width(5);
            line.color(R.color.palegreen);

            for (Location location : list) {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                        .getLongitude());
                line.add(latLng);
            }

            map.addPolyline(line);

        }
    });

}
```

}

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" >


 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/slide_bar_text"
    />

 <SeekBar android:id="@+id/slide_bar"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/palegreen"


      />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/slide_bar_text"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_above="@id/slide_bar"
     android:text="4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is very easy.
Use the following code:

```
Marker marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(latLng)
                 .title("Title")
                 .snippet("Snippet")
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                 .fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

marker.showInfoWindow();
```